# How to implement Stemmer search in Elasticsearch 6.1 on java

Tags: java, elasticsearch, porter-stemmer, elasticsearch-6

I need to implement stemmer search, I've found this [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-stemmer-tokenfilter.html#analysis-stemmer-tokenfilter) on elasticsearch documentation. There is json that I've had send to elascticsearch server. But I new in elasticsearch and cannot figure out how to implements this in java. I cannot also find any examples. Ccould you please help me with this?

I've add setting with

```
PUT /data
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis" : {
            "analyzer" : {
                "my_analyzer" : {
                    "tokenizer" : "standard",
                    "filter" : ["standard", "lowercase", "my_stemmer"]
                }
            },
            "filter" : {
                "my_stemmer" : {
                    "type" : "stemmer",
                    "name" : "english"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

after that I am trying to find 'skis' with query:

```
GET data/_search
{
  "query": {
    "simple_query_string": {
      "fields": [ "value36" ],
      "query": "ski"
    }
  }
}
```

but result is empty

Comment: Are you asking how to send the `settings` on the `JSON` request in `JAVA` or how to implement a stemming algorithm in `JAVA`? All those stemming algorithms in the link already exist in the search engine. You just need to pick one via the `setting`. Alternatively you can write your own stemmer in `JAVA` but that is a completely different question but there are plenty of code samples out there regarding the `porter-stemmer`.

Comment: I don't know how to add settings. First one

Comment: Is the index already created?  If your index contains a stemmer as part of the analysis of the index then you don't need to worry about setting a stemmer from java.

Comment: But what kind of query I have to use?